# How to add a fragment on tap of grid view items?

Tags: android

I am having tabs under which they have there own fragment.There is one tab whose fragment is having gridview items.I want that on tap of each item a new fragment should be open.Tab must be remain but fragment should be different.

Is this possible?...

Suggest me some possible way to do it..

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Yeas it is possible. First, you have to use GridView's setOnItemClickListener(), to set a listener gridviews click.

Then you can detect wich element has been clicked and make the transition. How do you implemented the tabs stuff? To make the transition you need the fragment manager and replace the fragment.

```
Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,fragment).commit();
```

Comment: Select it as answer if it works. To help you better put some code.